# i want user enter product name and quantity then using query show whether the stock available or no

Tags: python, django

please correct my code or guide me ho to do its giving me a error .... 
 error

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'quantity_onhand'
```

my funtion

```
def productsearch(request):
        product=request.GET.get('product')
        quantity=request.GET.get('quantity')
        product_result=Product.objects.all().filter(product_id=product)
        if ('quantity') > product_result.quantity_onhand:
            print('stock is not available')
        return render(request,'product/productlocation.html',{'product_result' : product_result,'quantity_result':quantity_result, 'product': product,'quantity':quantity})
```

template...

```
<body>
{% if quantity_result %}
 {% for r in quantity_result %}
{{r.quantity_onhand}} 
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <h3>no results</h3>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: "*please correct my code*" - not sure what you're expecting, but... you haven't shown what's actually wrong with it, the expected result, the result or error you get, etc. So this is essentially "why isn't my code working?" - which is off-topic. Please edit to be more specific. Otherwise, it's up to the community to inspect and debug your code for you.

Comment: @David Makogon  sir giving me an error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'quantity_onhand'

Comment: @rabia Your code is highly incomplete. Please provide a minimal working example outlining your problem

Comment: @FlyingTeller sir  i am new to django i want to do something like this how i m not figure out this

Comment: @FlyingTeller can u correct my function or template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are half a dozen issues here.

Firstly, `filter` always returns a queryset, hence the error you see. You are passing an exact ID, so you should use `get`:

```
product_result = Product.objects.all().get(product_id=product)
```

Next, your `if` statement compares the literal value `"quantity"`. You mean to compare the value of the variable `quantity`. However, since that value comes straight from the query dict, it's a string; you should convert it to an int:

```
if int(quantity) > product_result.quantity_onhand:
```

Next, there is no point printing the error message; you need to return it to your template.

Fourth, you don't define anything called `quantity_result` in your view, so you can't refer to it in the `render()` call; I'm not sure why you're doing that.

Fifth, in the template you are iterating over `quantity_result` which again does not exist; if you meant `product_result`, that is now a single Product item, so you can't iterate over it. You should remove that for loop and just access `{{ product_result.quantity_onhand }}`.